# Why does 11.10 use so much ram in unity but not gnome-shell

Tags: 11.10, unity

Why does 11.10 use so much ram in unity but not gnome-shell

It just seems to be an all-around resource hog. Windows 7 is less taxing. Even though ubuntu uses 550-700 mB on average it makes my fan go crazy, my computer hot, and is kinda slow. Windows 7 uses 1.45 gigs on average (mostly cache) is faster (in launching programs, about the same boot time) and more responsive and DOESn't make my fan run all the time and my computer stays at a decent temperature.

Comment: Uh.. Maybe it's somehting else, Unity is merely a big Compiz Plug in, it might be something else, Open up a terminal and type `htop` (install it if you don't have it).There you can see what processes are hogging your resources.

Comment: did you try unity-2d?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)